# <fo:basic-link> not creating clickable link XSL-FO XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, hyperlink, xsl-fo

Given this XML:

```
<figure id="fig-0011">
<title>Removal of Shipping Kit(s)</title>
<graphic id="fig-0011-gra-0001" infoEntityIdent="66503-00129-A-001-01"></graphic>
</figure>
```

and

```
<proceduralStep><para>Remove screw (see <internalRef internalRefId="fig-0011" internalRefTargetType="irtt01"></internalRef>) 
<proceduralStep><para>Remove two screws (10) (see <internalRef internalRefId="fig-0011-gra-0001" internalRefTargetType="irtt09"></internalRef>),
```

I'm trying to create links to the figures and graphics. The link to the figure is working correctly, but the link to the graphic is not:

```
<fo:basic-link>
<xsl:attribute name="internal-destination"><xsl:apply-templates select="//dmodule/identAndStatusSection/dmAddress/dmIdent/dmCode"/><xsl:value-of select="@internalRefId"/></xsl:attribute>
<xsl:variable name="targetElement" select="local-name(key('id',@internalRefId))"/>
<xsl:for-each select="key('id',(@internalRefId))">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$targetElement='graphic'">
            <xsl:text>Fig </xsl:text>
            <xsl:number count="figure" from="content" level="any"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$targetElement='figure'">
            <xsl:text>Fig </xsl:text>
            <xsl:number count="figure" from="content" level="any"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Key:

```
<xsl:key name="id" match="*" use="@id"/>
```

Figure:

```
<xsl:template match="figure">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="graphic"/>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="figure/graphic" priority="10">
    <fo:block text-align="center" start-indent="0pt" color="black" keep-with-next="always">
        <xsl:call-template name="do-graphic">
            <xsl:with-param name="include-graphic" select="true()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </fo:block>
    <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../legend"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@infoEntityIdent">
        <fo:block text-align="right" keep-with-previous="always">
            <xsl:value-of select="@infoEntityIdent"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:if>
    <fo:block font-weight="normal" font-style="italic" text-align="center" space-before="12pt" space-after="8pt" start-indent="0pt" keep-with-previous="always">
        <xsl:if test="../@id">
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:apply-templates select="//dmodule/identAndStatusSection/dmAddress/dmIdent/dmCode"/><xsl:value-of select="../@id"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>Fig  </xsl:text>
        <xsl:number count="figure" level="any" format="1" from="content"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../title"/>
        <xsl:variable name="numSheets" select="count(../graphic)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$numSheets>1">
                <xsl:text> (Sheet </xsl:text>
                <xsl:number count="graphic" level="any" format="1" from="figure"/>
                <xsl:text> of </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$numSheets"/>
                <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </fo:block>
```

Graphic:

```
<xsl:template match="graphic">
    <fo:inline-container>
        <fo:block space-before="12pt" space-before.conditionality="retain">
            <xsl:call-template name="do-graphic"/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:inline-container>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="do-graphic">
    <xsl:param name="include-graphic" select="true()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="content-width">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@reproductionWidth != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="@reproductionWidth"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- coding for reproduction scale based on clarifications in Issue 4.1 -->
            <xsl:when test="@reproductionScale != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="@reproductionScale"/>
                <xsl:text>%</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>95%</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="content-height">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@reproductionHeight != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="@reproductionHeight"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@reproductionScale != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="@reproductionScale"/>
                <xsl:text>%</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>95%</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$include-graphic">
            <fo:external-graphic src="{unparsed-entity-uri(@infoEntityIdent)}" scaling="uniform" content-height="{$content-height}" content-width="{$content-width}"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:inline-container display-align="center" text-align="center" block-progression-dimension="{$content-height}" inline-progression-dimension="{$content-width}" background-color="silver" color="red">
                <fo:block>Graphic Not Included</fo:block>
            </fo:inline-container>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This returns:

```
    Remove two screws (10) (see Fig 2)
```

which is the correct figure number, but the 2 is not a clickable link to the graphic.

The dmcode template builds a string. If I remove that from the XSLT then the figure number no longer links to the figure.

I am using XSLT 1.0. I appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The second `internalRef` refers to a `graphic`.  It appears that your XSLT is not copying the `graphic/@id` into the FO in the result tree.  With AH Formatter and a stylesheet that doesn't copy `graphic/@id`, I get no link and the error message:

```
Unresolved internal-destination: "fig-0011-gra-0001".
```

It appears that your FO formatter also isn't making the link when there's no matching target ID.

I can't help you much more without seeing your `xsl:key` declaration(s), the templates for `figure` and `graphic`, and knowing whether `graphic` can appear outside of `figure`.

---

Reedited to use `figure/@id` and `graphic/@id`:

```
<xsl:key name="id" match="*" use="@id" />

<xsl:variable name="prefix">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//dmodule/identAndStatusSection/dmAddress/dmIdent/dmCode" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="internalRef">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('id', @internalRefId)">
        <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{$prefix}{@id}">
            <xsl:text>Fig </xsl:text>
            <xsl:number count="figure" from="content" level="any" />
        </fo:basic-link>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="figure">
    <fo:wrapper id="{@id}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="graphic" />
    </fo:wrapper>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="figure/graphic" priority="10">
    <fo:block text-align="center" start-indent="0pt" color="black" keep-with-next="always">
        <xsl:if test="@id">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="$prefix" />
                <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:call-template name="do-graphic">
            <xsl:with-param name="include-graphic" select="true()" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </fo:block>
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../legend" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@infoEntityIdent">
        <fo:block text-align="right" keep-with-previous="always">
            <xsl:value-of select="@infoEntityIdent" />
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:if>
    <fo:block font-weight="normal" font-style="italic" text-align="center" space-before="12pt" space-after="8pt" start-indent="0pt" keep-with-previous="always">
        <xsl:text>Fig  </xsl:text>
        <xsl:number count="figure" level="any" format="1" from="content" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../title" />
        <xsl:variable name="numSheets" select="count(../graphic)" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$numSheets > 1">
                <xsl:text> (Sheet </xsl:text>
                <xsl:number count="graphic" level="any" format="1" from="figure" />
                <xsl:text> of </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$numSheets" />
                <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

I also moved the graphic's ID to the first `fo:block` in the `figure/graphic` template.  Having it on the last `fo:block` would have meant scrolling up to see the graphic every time that you followed a link to a graphic.

Comment: Thanks, Tony. `Graphic` cannot be outside of `figure`.

Comment: I appreciate your time, Tony. I did get this to work with your suggestions, however, often there is more than one graphic per figure and as expected the link always goes to the first figure. There are other items with ids, like `table` so I added `<xsl:key name="id" match="table" use="@id"/>` to the `xsl:key` declarations and that worked. Your solution is an improvement over what I had. My formatter is Antenna House 6.2.

Comment: Thanks, Tony, I did get the graphics link to work with your revised code. AH support pointed out I needed to add an `<xsl:attribute name="id">` to `<fo:external-graphic>` which was a little easier to implement. I am grateful for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

It was suggested to add `<xsl:attribute name="id">` to the `<fo:external-graphic>` in the do-graphic template and that seems to solve the problem:

```
<xsl:template name="do-graphic">
    <xsl:param name="include-graphic" select="true()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="content-width">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@reproductionWidth != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="@reproductionWidth"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="checkForUom">
                    <xsl:with-param name="measure" select="@reproductionWidth"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- coding for reproduction scale based on clarifications in Issue 4.1 -->
            <xsl:when test="@reproductionScale != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="@reproductionScale"/>
                <xsl:text>%</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>95%</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="content-height">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@reproductionHeight != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="@reproductionHeight"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="checkForUom">
                    <xsl:with-param name="measure" select="@reproductionWidth"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- coding for reproduction scale based on clarifications in Issue 4.1 -->
            <xsl:when test="@reproductionScale != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="@reproductionScale"/>
                <xsl:text>%</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>95%</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$include-graphic">
            <fo:external-graphic src="{unparsed-entity-uri(@infoEntityIdent)}" scaling="uniform" content-height="{$content-height}" content-width="{$content-width}">
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:apply-templates select="//dmodule/identAndStatusSection/dmAddress/dmIdent/dmCode"/><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
            </fo:external-graphic>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:inline-container display-align="center" text-align="center" block-progression-dimension="{$content-height}" inline-progression-dimension="{$content-width}" background-color="silver" color="red">
                <fo:block>Graphic Not Included</fo:block>
            </fo:inline-container>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```